# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a MERN application referring to a MERN tutorial. I'm stuck with an error and I tried searching with error but couldn't find the solution for this error.
I created the model of the user and exported as per document and imported the model in server.js but I'm couldn't find where did I made a mistake here.
Please find attached a screenshot for error in the cmd
[image]

please look into it

models/User.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Name is required!'
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Email is required!'
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Password is required!'
    },
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

server.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();
const app = require('./app');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err.message);
})

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB connected');
})

// Importing models
require('./models/User');
require('./models/Chatroom');
require('./models/Message');


app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 8000');
})
```

useController.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const sha256 = require('js-sha256');
const jwt = require('jwt-then');

// catchError on user routes expects async function so it defined with asyc()
exports.register = async(req, res) => {
    //... code
    })
}

exports.login = async(req, res) => {
    // ... code
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use `mongoose` for importing the `User` model. You can import it directly from the `models/User.js` file.

```
const Users = require('../models/User'); //Check if the path is correct
const sha256 = require('js-sha256');
const jwt = require('jwt-then');

// catchError on user routes expects async function so it defined with asyc()
exports.register = async(req, res) => {
    //... code
    })
}

exports.login = async(req, res) => {
    // ... code
    })
}
```